# How to read +--- and \--- in the dependencies output?

Tags: gradle

When I run the `dependencies` task, I see a dependency graph wherein some entries are preceded by `+---` and some entries are preceded by `\---`. What do each of these two symbols mean?

As an example, when I run `gradle :app:dependencies --configuration debugCompileClasspath` for an Android application, I see an entry as follows:

```
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.10
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.6.10
|    |    +--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
|    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.6.10
|    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.10
|         \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.6.10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`+---` marks the beginning of an expansion of the list on inner dependencies for the entry next to it.
In your case, it starts the list of the dependencies for `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.10`. As you can see, the next line is a bit indented, that's the first dependency of the parent `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.10`.

`\---` marks the end of the expansion of the list that was opened on that depth. In your case, `\--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.10` is the last dependency from `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.10`'s list. And that dependency has only one inner dependency which is `org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.6.10`.

A lot of dependencies but I lack a better word. I hope I don't confuse you even more :D

Comment: Perfect. This explains it. `\---` marks the final item in a list of items at a certain depth/indentation and `+--` marks a non-final item. Thank you very much for your answer 

Answer (score 1):

This is character-based artwork indicating an increased level of nesting; the symbols themselves don't mean anything beyond their visual appearance.  A nested item is a [transitive dependency](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/dependency_management_terminology.html#sub:terminology_transitive_dependency) of the item it's nested under.

### Example

Taking your example:

```
+--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.10
|    +--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.6.10
|    |    +--- org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
|    |    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.6.10
|    \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.10
|         \--- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.6.10
```

In this example, both `kotlin-stdlib` and `kotlin-stdlib-jdk7` are transitive dependencies of `kotlin-stdlib-jdk8`.  Likewise, both `annotations` & `kotlin-stdlib-common` are transitive dependencies of `kotlin-stdlib`.  `kotlin-stdlib` is a transitive dependency of `kotlin-stdlib-jdk7`.

In standard HTML list form, this rendering would be identical to:

- org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.10

  - org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.6.10

    - org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
    - org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.6.10
  - org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.6.10

    - org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.6.10

The following is a different textual rendering of the list, using drawing-based characters rather than purely ASCII ones, that may make things clearer:

```
┌─── org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.10
│    │
│    ├─── org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.6.10
│    │    │
│    │    ├─── org.jetbrains:annotations:13.0
│    │    │
│    │    └─── org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-common:1.6.10
│    │
│    └─── org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin.stdlib-jdk7:1.6.10
│         │
│         └─── org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.6.10
```

In this example, instead of `├───` to indicate a nested item with further items below, Gradle uses `+---`; instead of `└───` to indicate the last nested item, it uses `\---`.